# Issue when duplicating element in a form -> same names

Tags: jquery

So I got this:

***HTML***

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
   <td>

   </td>
   <td>

   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      3. Choose elements:
   </td>
   <td>
      <select name="antal_tidspunkter" id="antal_tidspunkter">
         <option value="1" SELECTED>1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
         <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
    <tr class="highlightedRowStart">
   <td class="borderLeft">
      Time
   </td>
   <td class="borderRight">
      <select name="seats_timeclock[29]">
         <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
         <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
         <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
         <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
         <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
         <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
         <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
         <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
         <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
         <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
         <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
         <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
         <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
         <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
         <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
         <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
         <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
         <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
         <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
         <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
         <option value="18:00" SELECTED>18:00</option>
         <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
         <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
         <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
         <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
         <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
         <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
         <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
         <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
         <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="highlightedRowMiddle">
   <td class="borderLeft">
      2:
   </td>
   <td class="borderRight">
      <select name="seats_free_2tables[29]">
         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2" SELECTED>2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
         <option value="5">5</option>
         <option value="6">6</option>
         <option value="7">7</option>
         <option value="8">8</option>
         <option value="9">9</option>
         <option value="10">10</option>
         <option value="11">11</option>
         <option value="12">12</option>
         <option value="13">13</option>
         <option value="14">14</option>
         <option value="15">15</option>
         <option value="16">16</option>
         <option value="17">17</option>
         <option value="18">18</option>
         <option value="19">19</option>
         <option value="20">20</option>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="">
   <td class="borderLeft">
     4:
   </td>
   <td class="borderRight">
      <select name="seats_free_4tables[29]">
         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4" SELECTED>4</option>
         <option value="5">5</option>
         <option value="6">6</option>
         <option value="7">7</option>
         <option value="8">8</option>
         <option value="9">9</option>
         <option value="10">10</option>
         <option value="11">11</option>
         <option value="12">12</option>
         <option value="13">13</option>
         <option value="14">14</option>
         <option value="15">15</option>
         <option value="16">16</option>
         <option value="17">17</option>
         <option value="18">18</option>
         <option value="19">19</option>
         <option value="20">20</option>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="highlightedRowEnd">
   <td class="borderLeft">
      Converttable
   </td>
   <td class="borderRight">
      <select name="seats_converttables[29]">
         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2" SELECTED>2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
         <option value="5">5</option>
         <option value="6">6</option>
         <option value="7">7</option>
         <option value="8">8</option>
         <option value="9">9</option>
         <option value="10">10</option>
         <option value="11">11</option>
         <option value="12">12</option>
         <option value="13">13</option>
         <option value="14">14</option>
         <option value="15">15</option>
         <option value="16">16</option>
         <option value="17">17</option>
         <option value="18">18</option>
         <option value="19">19</option>
         <option value="20">20</option>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="spacer">
   <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

***jQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#antal_tidspunkter").bind("change", function() {
        $("#mytable tr:gt(6)").remove();
        for (var i = 1; i < this.value; i++) {
            $("#mytable tr:gt(1):lt(5)").clone().appendTo("#mytable");
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bTWQg/

Works like this, when you change the number of elements in the selector, it adds more elements.

My issue with this is that when it duplicate the element, it keeps the name: `seats_timeclock[29]` so later when I'm working with the handling of the form (**PHP**), I only receive one element's data.

Is there anyway to add a random number inside `[]` from `11111, 99999` each time the element gets duplicated? Otherwise i can't grab the data filled on the new elements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // function to generate random number
    // between 1111 to 9999

    function randNum() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 1111 + 1)) + 1111;
    }

    $("#antal_tidspunkter").bind("change", function() {
        $("#mytable tr:gt(6)").remove();
        for (var i = 1; i < this.value; i++) {
            $("#mytable tr:gt(1):lt(5)")
                .clone()
                .find('select[name^=seats_timeclock]')
                attr('name', function() { // changing the name
                    return 'seats_timeclock_[' + randNum() + ']';
                })
                .end() // go back to clone element
                .appendTo("#mytable");
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bTWQg/7/)**

Above code will work without changing HTML and with a single chain statement.

#### According to your demo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // function to generate random number
    function randNum() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 1111 + 1)) + 1111;
    }
    $("#antal_tidspunkter").bind("change", function() {
        $("#mytable tr:gt(6)").remove();
        for (var i = 1; i < this.value; i++) {
            var randnr = randNum();
            
            $("#mytable tr:gt(1):lt(5)")
                .clone()
                .find('select[name^=seats_timeclock]')
                .attr('name', function() { // changing the name
                    return 'seats_timeclock[' + randnr + ']';
                })
                .end() // need to put end to jump to clone
                .find('select[name^=seats_free_2tables]')
                .attr('name', function() { // changing the name
                    return 'seats_free_2tables[' + randnr + ']';
                })
                .end()  // need to put end to jump to clone
                .find('select[name^=seats_free_4tables]')
                .attr('name', function() { // changing the name
                    return 'seats_free_4tables[' + randnr + ']';
                })
                .end()  // need to put end to jump to clone
                .find('select[name^=seats_converttables]')
                .attr('name', function() { // changing the name
                    return 'seats_converttables[' + randnr + ']';
                })
                .end() // go back to clone element
                .appendTo("#mytable");
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bTWQg/10/)**

Comment: @Karem please check my answer and demo

Comment: this works GREAT!!  Although I forgot to mention that; It should also change to the same random number for seats_free_4tables[random] and seats_converttables[random] , hope you can help with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#antal_tidspunkter").bind("change", function() {
        $("#mytable tr:gt(6)").remove();
        for (var i = 1; i < this.value; i++) {
            $("#mytable tr:gt(1):lt(5)").clone().children("select").attr("name", "seats_free_2tables[" + random() + "]").appendTo("#mytable");
        }
     });
});​
```

And for that `random()` function, use this code:

```
function random()
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
}
```

---

### Update: This code totally works:

```
function random()
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#antal_tidspunkter").bind("change", function() {
        $("#mytable tr:gt(6)").remove();
        for (var i = 1; i < this.value; i++) {
            var a = $("#mytable tr:gt(1):lt(5)").clone();
            a.find(".random").attr("name", "seats_free_2tables[" + random() + "]");
            a.appendTo("#mytable");
        }
    });
});​
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTWQg/5/). Give a class `random` to all, which you need to change!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried but nothing happens now, when you change #antal_tidspunkter. It should by the way also change to the same random number for seats_free_4tables[random] and seats_converttables[random]

Comment: Lemme edit the code ad paste the fiddle here. It is not at all working.

Comment: See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTWQg/5/). Give a class `random` to all, which you need to change!

Comment: Tried and it worked perfect front end, but back end after the form submits it does not grab the values bounded to the new []s ? Something is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You could use array inputs:

```
<select name="seats_timeclock[]">
```

That way you can add as many inputs as you want in the form, and they will be properly packed and sent by the browser.

Then, in PHP, you will have `$_POST['seats_timeclock'][0]`,  `$_POST['seats_timeclock'][1]` and so on. You could easily loop through that array.

```
foreach($_POST['seats_timeclock'] as $key => $seats_timeclock) {
    // the other array posts, will be serialized in the same way, 
    // so you can access the other fields having the same index
    $seats_free_2tables = $_POST['seats_free_2tables'][$key];
    $seats_free_4tables = $_POST['seats_free_4tables'][$key];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I need the number, I have your code for the create page, but this issue is coming at the edit page, where i need the number which is the id for updating the correct element

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the `name` attribute after you clone the element :

```
  var clone = $("#mytable tr:gt(1):lt(5)").clone();
  var min = 1111;
  var max = 9999;
  var number = Math.round(Math.random() * (max-min)) + min ; 
  clone.find('select[name^=seats_timeclock]')
       .attr('name','seats_timeclock['+number+']');
  clone.appendTo("#mytable");
```

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/bTWQg/3/

Comment: '29' is not fixed, it could be 99999 too, so it wouldnt workout

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clonedObj;
    $("#antal_tidspunkter").bind("change", function() {
        $("#mytable tr:gt(6)").remove();
        for (var i = 1; i < this.value; i++) {
            clonedObj = $("#mytable tr:gt(1):lt(5)").clone();
            $(clonedObj).find('select[name="seats_timeclock[29]"]').attr('name', 'seats_timeclock[' + Math.floor((Math.random()*100000)+1) + ']');
            $(clonedObj).appendTo("#mytable");
        }
     });
});​
```

**EDIT:** With support for variable numbers inside `seats_timeclock`. Makes use of jQuery [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function and a simple regex.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clonedObj;
    $("#antal_tidspunkter").bind("change", function() {
        $("#mytable tr:gt(6)").remove();
        for (var i = 1; i < this.value; i++) {
            clonedObj = $("#mytable tr:gt(1):lt(5)").clone();
            $(clonedObj).find('select').filter(function(){
                if($(this).attr('name').match(/seats_timeclock/)){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }                   
            }).attr('name', 'seats_timeclock[' + Math.floor((Math.random()*100000)+1) + ']');
            $(clonedObj).appendTo("#mytable");
        }
     });
});​
```

Comment: '29' is not fixed, it could be 99999 too, so it wouldnt workout

Comment: Then simply create a callback function and regex a select field that contains `seats_timeclock`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a solution for dynamically indexed names.